# Graphing Polynomial Fit for Solar Data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have spent approximately 2.5 hours sitting here trying to get a very simple thing to work but I've got to that point where I can't see it with fresh eyes. So despite it being straightforward I could really do with some help as I'm getting frustrated.

The problem is to plot a polynomial in python, simple right?
So I've obtained a polynomial fit from excel which actually looks very much like a gaussian, but that's not important. However, my plotting code seems unable to handle it. Despite code in my project operating in exactly the same manner without issue.

Ignore the random import as it was just a copy and paste jobby from my main document.

It should look like the photo I have attached. But currently it's blowing up in my face. It's likely a really simple issue but I've stared at it for far too long and so am blind to it.

Many thanks to those that take the time to help me out. I really apprecciate it!
[image: the resulting plot]

```
import numpy as np 
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

timebase = 1440
t0 = 0
ts = np.arange(t0, timebase, 1) # Create range between 0 and Max with 1 min spacing 

def solar():
    values = np.array( range(timebase), dtype = float) # Irradiance ie// Power / m^2
    # Solar Irradiance Parameters:

    for t in range(timebase):
        if 0 <= t < 210:
            values[t] = 0.00
        if 210 <= t < 1290:
            values[t] = ( (-2.00E-16)*(t**6) ) + ( (9.00E-13)*(t**5) ) - ( (1.00E-9)*(t**4) ) + ( (1.00E-6)*(t**3) ) - ( (0.0004)*(t**2) ) + ( (0.0795)*(t) ) - 5.4647
        if t >= 1290:
            values[t] = 0.00

     # Irradiance Efficiency Parameters
    return values

Test_sol =  solar()

pyplot.plot(ts, Test_sol, color = 'b', linewidth = 0.5)
pyplot.ylabel("Solar Power, kW") 
pyplot.xlabel("Time (Minutes)") 
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.ylim(0,)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: If you plot your function via wolframalpha.com, for t=0 to 3000, you see a complete different curve as on the photo. The formula must be wrong, or there must be some strange kind of transformation between t and x.

Comment: Very probable, is that you need many more significant digits than those displayed. Can you get more digits from the equation on the photo?

Comment: JohanC, you solved it! The significant digits were screwing it up. I’d have never thought it would have made such a difference. Either way, thank you very much